# Class issues: should I use everywhere self as class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

Wow, great issue I have found for myself.

What is it? The candy or the garlic?

**something about Objective-C:**

Are there any issues not to use 'self' in (+) - class methods as class?

in the deep of a class...

```
+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    return [self dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

**Ruby here:**
For example, in Ruby everything is object and class is object of class Class and there is a good practice to rely on self:

```
class DateClass 
     # self is DateClass here, inside of class definition, uh
     self.dateWithTimeInterval(interval)
         self.dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970(interval)
     end
end
```

**Perl here:**
Another example was found in perl oop deep: (thanks for [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=373638))

```
sub new {
    my $proto = shift || die "Must pass a class or object into new()";
    my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
    bless {}, $class;
}
```

So, in Perl and in Ruby guys always rely on `$class` refs

Maybe example with Perl code not obvious, but it happens all time. Programmers rely on $class reference and take class name with it. also, they can invoke some methods with it:

```
 my $class = 'Class';
    $class->new();
```

or

```
    Class::->new()
```

**After all...**

Which pitfalls or caveats could you provide against usage self as class in objective-c?

Comment: Are you asking for pros and cons for `[self dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];` VS. `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];` ?

Comment: @Visput, yes, about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you use `self` whenever you can but of course, there are situations when referencing the class by `[MyClass class]` is desired. Almost all of the scenarios are related to inheritance.

For example, a creator method for a class `A.`

```
@implementation A

+ (id)createInstanceWithParam:(NSInteger)param {
   return [[self alloc] initWithParam:param];
}

@end
```

Will work correctly even if we create a subclass `B`. However, if we decide to implement a class cluster, then we have to reference classes by names:

```
@implementation SomeDataStructure

+ (id)createInstanceWithType:(NSInteger)type {
    if (type == 0) {
       return [[DataStructureImpl1 alloc] init];
    }
    else if (type == 1) {
       return [[DataStructureImpl2 alloc] init];
    }
}

@end
```

Another example is the common example of `+initialize`

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [MyClass class]) {
        ...perform initialization...
    }
}
```

And of course, if you are overriding a method, then using `self` or using `[MySelf class]` can be a distinction between your overriden implementation and the original implementation. Although `super` could be used there, too.

**TLDR:**
`self` is preferred but be careful with subclasses/superclasses.

Comment: thanks for examples. but why you use equality by `==`? is it safe for class comparison?

Comment: It's absolutely safe, the `initialize` example is directly from Apple documentation. There is only one instance of metaclass, always.

Answer (score 1):

For understanding pros and cons of using `self` vs. `class name` let's consider one situation:
Class `A` is subclass of `NSDate` and implements method `+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval`.

Class `B` is subclass of `A` and overrides implementation of `+dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)interval` method that declared in `NSDate`.

Now let's consider two possible implementations of `+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval` method in `A`:

**1.** Using `self`

```
+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    return [self dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

if run `[B dateWithTimeInterval:interval];` then `self` in above code is kind of `B` class and as expected custom implementation (in class `B`) for `+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)interval` method would be called.

**2.** Using directly `NSDate`

```
+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

if run `[B dateWithTimeInterval:interval];` then overridden implementation (in class `B`) would be ignored and instead of it: original implementation (in class `NSDate`) for `+(NSDate*)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)interval` method would be called. It's so because we directly send message to `NSDate`: `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];`.
This behavior is unexpected for developer.

For the same reason declare methods in such way:

```
+(instancetype)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    return [self dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

By using `instancetype` compiler will know what kind of object is returned by method-initializer. When you call `[B dateWithTimeInterval:interval]` it returns object of kind `B` but not `NSDate`.